# Android: View on the design preview is not like the real

Tags: android, android-layout, preview

there is code of my layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="119dp"
        android:layout_height="84dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image_template"
        android:id="@+id/roleIco"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="the name of the player"
        android:id="@+id/playerName"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Role name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/roleName"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Fraction"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fractionName"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="74dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_heart"
        android:id="@+id/playerStatusIcon"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />


</LinearLayout>
```

And the problem is that, in Design preview in Android Studio it looks like that:
[See this image, please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8o2i.png)

But when i launch this app on the phone it looks like this:

[See this image, please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzcRp.png)

Somebody could help me what is the reason on this difference and how to eliminate it and change the real view to this like on the preview?

Thanks for answer ;)

Comment: are you referring to text color in preview??

Comment: You have not set orientation for parent linear layout. Try setting its orientation to `horizontal`.

Comment: @Vaibhav Agarwal default orientation is always horizontal even when you don't define it

Comment: Oh yes! My bad. How could I forget that. Thanks for correcting me. @Vivek Mishra

Answer (score 0):

**Preview** is different because you are **seeing preview according to API Level 24** while the image that you attached for **real device is below API Level 21**.

Therefore there is **no Material Design** available in your real device and hence there is the difference. **Try it in a real device running Android Lollipop or higher** you will get same results.